# Log4Net - Sample from Apache creates 10 rolling files on startup (but mine doesn't)

Tags: log4net

I tried out the log4net sample from Apache under C# 2.0, consoleapp.  It seems to create 10 rolling files before it ever needs to roll.  I created basically the exact same app but I use XmlConfigurator.Configure(fileName) instead of putting the config inside the app.config like it is in the example.  In my app, no extra rolling files are created ahead of time.  In the Apache sample, 10 files appear immediately.

Has anyone else ever noticed this?

I can post my app details, but I am mostly interested in the Apache sample C# console app.

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doh!

This was just silly.  The sample specifies a super tiny rollover size.

The issue went away with:

```
  <maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="10" />
```